# CSS Aligning two DIVs side-by-side in the center. with position absolute

Tags: css, css-position

I was wondering how to align two  elements side-by-side to the center of the page with position absolute. But when I am trying, I don't get that right. For my code, refer to this link: http://jsfiddle.net/6FnRr/

So basically this is what I want:

```
 ______________________                        _________
|                      |                      |         |
|                      |                      |         |
|                      |                      |         |
|______________________| (5px Gap here)       |_________|
```

In the wrapper, they have `position: absolute;` Both those containers must be aligned side-by-side in the center with 5px gap between them. Please help me out, I have no idea how. I tried every single thing I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested to use `display: inline-block` + `text-align: center;` + `vertical-align: top` :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FnRr/5/)

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNMXa/)

Try this css:

```
#work_holder {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* parent should be relative */
    clear: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#work_container {
    background: #FFFF00;
    position:absolute; /* child absolute relatively to the parent*/
    width: 681px;
    height: 256px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#work_details {
    background: #00FF00;
     position:absolute; /* child absolute relatively to the parent */
    left:686px; /* 681px + 5px;*/
    width: 223px;
    height: 256px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute! You want float: left.

```
.myblocks {
    float: left;
}
.myfirstblock {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Make sure you [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) it after.

Comment: I need absolute due to other divs... it wont show, so until I put position: absolute, the div stays hidden.

Comment: If you're using absolute, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: i am using absolute because, when I write <div> it goes to the top of the page and doesnt show.. so when I put position: absolute; it shows...

Comment: Because it's bloody huge? :L

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/6FnRr/3/

```
  #work_holder {
        width: 100%;
        position: abosulte;
    }
    #work_container {
        background: #FFFF00;
        position:absolute;
        width: 681px;
        height: 256px;
        float: left;
    }
    #work_details {
        background: #00FF00;
         position:absolute;
        left:686px;
        width: 223px;
        height: 256px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your div's right and left to center of the page and add margin to both for gap. This will align the gap exactly on the center of your wrapper div. Here is **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/f2WPa/1/)**.

```
#work_holder {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    clear: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#work_container {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFF00;
    width: 681px;
    height: 256px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#work_details {
    position: absolute;
    background: #00FF00;
    width: 223px;
    height: 256px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 3px;;
}
```